# How to use DI with Startup class in .net Core 2.0 Unit Test project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core, integration-testing

i have a .net Core 2.0 Unit Test Project, in which I would like to perform some unit tests on my data class libraries.

However, in this Unit Test Project, i would like to use:
- Startup.cs
- Dependency Injection

So far, I have included the following additional NuGet Packages:

```
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (2.0.0)
- Microsoft.Extensioins.DependencyInjection (2.0.0)
```

Also, I have created a Startup.cs in which I would like to use the default built-in injection of the configuration file (appsettings.json):

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IConfiguration _config { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");

        services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }
}
```

Now I get stuck.

I cannot create a constructor overload with a parameter in my test class, which I thought would be the way to go forward, like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestHelpers
{
    private MyDataContext _context;
    private UnitOfWork _uow;
    private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;

    public TestHelpers(MyDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        _uow = new UnitOfWork(_context);
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
```

This does not work, as the MS TestFramework requires a parameterless constructor. So, i cannot 'inject' my datacontext in the constructor of the test class.

How do I proceed with this?

Also, I do not think my Startup.Cs class is instantiated. How do I do this in my Test project?

Answer (score 3):

> I do not think my Startup.Cs class is instantiated. How do I do this in my Test project?

You don't.

Your Startup.cs runs to bootstrap your *application*, with classes that actually talk to the outside world (e.g. databases).

In your unit test, you mock the dependencies, so you just test the current unit and not its dependencies. So your test class will look something like this:

```
public TestHelpers()
{
    _context = new Mock<MyDataContext>();

    _uow = new UnitOfWork(_context.Object);
}
```

Instead of a mock, you could also use an in-memory database made for testing. See also [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory).

Comment: So you cannot use the startup class in a unit test project, only in web/console applications?

Comment: I agree with CodeCaster on this, there is no real reason to use DI in *unit* tests (integration tests may be another story). Typically, you never have more than a half dozen dependencies or so for any given unit test, 1 class under test, and the rest are either mocks or DTOs. In this scenario, a DI container will only over complicate and get in the way of your unit testing.

Comment: Unless you want to use an appconfig.json for storing connection strings or variable endpoints. And use the built-int DI to load them up. I suppose you could also hard-code these values in the test classes....

Comment: @SlimSjakie no, the point of a unit test is that it _doesn't_ talk to your actual database. So you don't need connection strings.